# How to dispatch an action from select

Tags: reactjs, redux

I would like to update a piece of state and then dispatch an action with that piece of state in the same onChange. I need this to happen after a select option is chosen.

Currently the onChange is only firing when the page loads. I want the select to have the ability to fetch data when option is selected and then render a new select below it with the fetched data as options to choose from

I am using Mern stack

Here is my code below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Card, CardBody, CustomInput, Button, Input, Label, Form } from 'reactstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import Select from 'react-select';
import FalconCardHeader from '../common/FalconCardHeader';
import CustomCardSummary from '../common/CustomCardSummary';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { findANumber } from '../../actions/index';
import numbers from '../../data/billing/area-codes';



const BuyNewNumbers = () => {
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('US');
  const [areaCode, setAreaCode] = useState('');
  const [numberType, setNumberType] = useState('')
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors, watch } = useForm();


 useEffect(() => {
   
 }, [])


  return (

    <Card className="h-100">
      <FalconCardHeader className="text-center"title="Buy a new number" light={false} />
      <CardBody tag={Form} className="bg-light" onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
      <CustomCardSummary color="success"className="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <span className="fs-1">Choose your Country</span>
          <div className="mb-2"></div>
        <CustomInput
          type="select"
          id="country"
          name="country"
          className="mb-3"
          value={country}
          onChange={({ target }) => setCountry(target.value)}
        >
          <option value="US">United States</option>
          <option value="CA">Canada</option>
          
        </CustomInput>
        {console.log(country)}
        <span className="fs-1">Choose Number Type</span>
        <div className="mb-2"></div>

        <CustomInput
          type="select"
          id="numberType"
          name="numberType"
          className="mb-3"
          value={country}
          onChange={({ target }) => setNumberType(target.value)} // dispatch an action and map over array of available area codes from twilio
          > 
            
            <option value="local">Local</option>
            <option value="Toll fre">Toll free</option>

          </CustomInput>
        </CustomCardSummary>
        <span className="fs-1">Area Code</span>
          <div className="mb-2"></div>
         

        <Select 
          name="areacodes"
          isSearchable
          options={numbers}
          styles={customStyles}
          onChange={ 
            setAreaCode,
            console.log(areaCode)
          
          }

          />
        <hr />
        {console.log(areaCode)}
        <h5 className="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <span>Price per month</span>
          <span>$4.00</span>
        </h5>
        <p className="fs--1 text-600">
        We will deduct this amount from your account balance each month. If your account balance becomes too low to renew the dedicated number, 
        we leave right to cancel it permanently. You can cancel this number at any time.
        </p>
        <div className="align-items-right">
        <Button className="mx-2"type="submit" color="danger">Cancel</Button>
        <Button type="submit" color="primary">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="plus" className="mr-2" />
          Activate number
        </Button>
        </div>
       
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
  };


export default BuyNewNumbers;
```

Comment: can you provide codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Just call `dispatch` like this:

```
onChange={({ target }) => {
  setNumberType(target.value)}
  dispatch(...)
  // another logic
}
```